# Outlook calendar Syncing issue

Tags: .net, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I am using Microsoft graph library for syncing the events but its returning always top 10 events but my requirement are below,
1- Get the count of events between date range.
2-Get all events between date range.

Code are,

```
 GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
                        {
                            requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", userEmail);

                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));


var eventResults = client.Me.Events.Request()
                        .GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: By the way, the X-AnchorMailbox header is probably unnecessary. The routing hint is in the URL. /me/....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the calendar events in a specific range you have to use calendarView (see [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview)). Using graph SDK it could look like this.

```
        List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
        List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>()
                        {
                            new QueryOption("startDateTime",startDateTime),
                            new QueryOption("endDateTime",endDateTime),
                            //new QueryOption("$top",top),
                            //new QueryOption("$select",select)
                        };

        var request = graphClient.Users[userId].Calendar.CalendarView.Request(options);

        var result = await request.GetAsync();

        if (result != null)
        {
            eventList.AddRange(result);

            var nextPage = result;
            while (nextPage.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                var nextPageRequest = nextPage.NextPageRequest;
                nextPage = await nextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                if (nextPage != null)
                {
                    eventList.AddRange(nextPage);
                }
            }
        }
```

Get the event count with `eventList.Count`.